# jQTouch for iPhone - Quick Troubleshoot?

Tags: jquery, iphone, jqtouch

Could someone with knowledge of jQTouch for the iPhone have a quick look at my source and let me know what the heck I'm doing wrong? Clicking the big green buttons is supposed to reveal that particular section.

http://designsnack.com/mobile/

Answer (score 3):

Safari (both on the iPhone and on the desktop) reports 10 errors in your HTML code. My short experience with jQTouch and Safari on the iPhone is, that thet can both be a bit picky about this.

Here's how you on Safari's debug console on the iPhone and on the desktop: [Overview of Developer Tools for Safari](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/2SafariDeveloperTools/SafariDeveloperTools.html).